# iOS Swift using getter and setter or direct access?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and iOS and I'm trying to figure out what is the recommended approach for setting and getting values. I've noticed that in the build in classes there is a lot of direct access compared to Android (where I come from). So what does iOS veterans do and why? And is there some kind of recommended approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spite of being syntactically identical, accessing Swift properties is not the same as accessing Java variables, When you expose a variable in Java, like this

```
class MyClass {
    public int val = 123;
}
```

you have no way of protecting it at some later time without breaking everyone else's code that reads and writes `c.val` variable.

Swift properties, on the other hand, let you add custom getters and setters to something that looks like a variable at the beginning:

```
class MyClass {
    public var val = 123
}
```

If you decide that you want a setter later, you can change this to

```
class MyClass {
    private var _val = 123
    public var val : Int {
        get {
            return _val
        }
        set (newVal) {
            precondition(newVal >= 0, "Negative values are not allowed")
            _val = newVal
        }
    }
}
```

This is because when you write `c.val = -321` Swift executes the code of the setter, i.e. what looks like a direct access is actually a method call.

Comment: Okay so I understand what goes on now but I guess when I make variables I have to implement it in a similar fashion to get the same results. Is that recommended? Wont it get confusing for others if they have direct access or actually are using a method?

Comment: @Warpzit This was a little confusing in Objective-C, which supported both directly-accessed variables and properties. I think Swift took out the confusion out of it by erasing the difference between a field and a property, making it impossible to have a field that you cannot protect. Of course there are situations when you want a method call for clarity - for example, if a property is write-only, it's best to replace it with a method.

Answer (score 2):

What looks like an assignment is actually a setter, and what looks like reading a member is actually a getter. The class usually has a primitive setter that just assigns or reads values, but that can be overridden with any code you want. In addition, there are didSet / willSet where the class can add code to react to changes.

You never write code that *looks* like you are calling a setter or getter, but you are actually calling them.

If you find that you are executing a lot of code when a getter or setter is called, which would be unexpected to a caller, you use a function instead.